# C++ Compile time specific functions with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I'm currently working on a library for function abstraction. I want to abstract a multi-parameter-function to a one-parameter-function which is an index. Optionally I want to pass a predicate object which determines if it should run the code.

```c++
using FnType = std::function<void(const unsigned long)>;

template<typename Fn, typename Predicate, typename ... Args>
const FnType make_fn(const Fn &fn, const Predicate &predicate, Args ... args) {
    return [&](const unsigned long idx) {
        if(predicate(idx)) fn(idx, args ...);
    };
}

template<typename Fn, typename ... Args>
const FnType make_fn(const Fn &fn, Args ... args) {
    return [&](const unsigned long idx) {
        fn(idx, args ...);
    };
}
```

This code works perfectly when using a predicate.

```c++
std::vector<double> data(10);
auto fn = [&](unsigned idx, double d) { data[idx] *= d; };
auto pred = [](unsigned long idx) { return idx % 2 == 0; };
FnType new_fn = make_fn(fn, pred, 2.0);
```

But when I try to pass no predicate

```c++
FnType new_fn2 = make_fn(fn, 2.0);
```

it returns the following compile time error message:

```c++
called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer
    if(predicate(idx)) fn(idx, args ...);
       ^~~~~~~~~
```

Is there any possibility to say the compiler it should use the second function which does not use any predicate?

Comment: You may want to change your title. You'll give people heart attacks by saying "varargs" for C++

Comment: Does 'variadic templates' sound better? ;)

Comment: Note you have a bug - you take `args` by value, but you capture them by reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at your signatures:

```
template<typename Fn, typename Predicate, typename ... Args>
const FnType make_fn(const Fn&, const Predicate&, Args ...); // (1)

template<typename Fn, typename ... Args>
const FnType make_fn(const Fn&, Args ... ) // (2)
```

When we call with:

```
make_fn(fn, 2.0);
```

There isn't anything special about `Predicate` - it's just another type. So when we do overload resolution, we have two exact matches. The way we resolve variadic parameters is that `(1)` is more specialized than `(2)` - since `(1)` takes at least 2 arguments and `(2)` takes at least 1 argument, the former is more specific. That's why we call the former. The compiler doesn't know from the signature what you mean by `Predicate`.

The simplest solution would be to simply **rename** one function or the other - do you really need them to be overloaded? Have a `make_fn()` and a `make_predicate_fn()`.

Alternatively, we *could* change that with SFINAE, by enforcing that `Predicate` is callable:

```
template <typename Fn, typename Predicate, typename... Args,
          typename = decltype(std::declval<Predicate>()(0u))>
const FnType make_fn(const Fn&, const Predicate&, Args ...);
```

That would make `(1)` ill-formed for your call, so `(2)` would be preferred. Though this additionally has the downside of what if you don't want to use the predicate in this way, but instead simply have some function whose first argument is a predicate? The wrong thing would happen.

A better fix proposed by T.C. in comments is to just introduce an empty tag type:

```
struct predicate_tag_t { };
constexpr predicate_tag_t predicate_tag{};
```

And overload on the presence of that tag:

```
template <typename Fn, typename Predicate, typename... Args>
FnType make_fn(const Fn&, predicate_tag_t, const Predicate&, Args&&... );

template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
FnType make_fn(const Fn&, Args&&... );
```

That way your examples become:

```
FnType new_fn = make_fn(fn, predicate_tag, pred, 2.0);
FnType new_fn2 = make_fn(fn, 2.0);
```

---

You have dangling references in both `make_fn`s when you have:

```
const FnType make_fn(const Fn &fn, Args ... args) {
    return [&](const unsigned long idx) { ... }
}
```

You're copying all your args, and then holding references to all of them. But once `make_fn` completes, all the `args` go out of scope. You'll need to copy them - so `[=]`.

Comment: I understand. So you mean that being more explicit with the predicate type should solve the problem? I tried using the type 'std::function<bool(unsigned long)> but now the compiler says: "in instantiation of function template specialization 'make_fn<(lambda at ...), (lambda at ...), double>' ... candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided.

Comment: @dommynik I didn't say to use `std::function`. That would cause `(2)` to be preferred even if you pass a predicate, due to it having a better conversion sequence.

Comment: Is this the right implementation? `template<typename Fn, typename Predicate, typename ... Args,
             typename = decltype(std::declval<Predicate>()(0u))>
    auto make_fn(const Fn &fn, const Predicate &predicate, Args && ... args) {
        return [&](const unsigned long idx) {
            if(predicate(idx)) fn(idx, std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
        };
    }`

Comment: The SFINAE is quite fragile. I'd make the recommendation to use different names stronger (or use a tag type - say, `struct predicate_arg_t {};`). Also, the captures need to be by value; forwarding is not enough - it's way too easy to create dangling references (for example, `FnType new_fn2 = make_fn(fn, 2.0);` will always dangle if you store a reference.)

Comment: @T.C. What do you mean by using tag types? Using capture by value I got this (and it works stable): `template<typename Fn, typename Predicate, typename ... Args,
             typename = decltype(std::declval<Predicate>()(0u))>
    FnType make_fn(Fn fn, Predicate predicate, Args const & ... args) {
        return [=](const unsigned long idx) {
            if(predicate(idx)) fn(idx, args ...);
        };
    }` - by using `std::forward` I got segmentation faults.

Answer (score 1):

Change your upper function to

```
template<typename Fn, typename Predicate, typename ... Args
       , typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof ... (Args) != 0> >
const FnType make_fn(const Fn &fn, const Predicate &predicate, Args ... args) {
    return [=](const unsigned long idx) {
        if(predicate(idx)) fn(idx, args ...);
    };
}
```

This ensures there is at least one member of the parameter pack, and then the second function is selected during overload resolution.

Some more things to note:

- Better make the return type `auto` -- you can still asign it to a `std::function`, but requires less overhead if you simply call it.
- Probably you don't want to pass the general parameters in `Args ...` by value, so better write `Args const& ... args`.

Comment: What if we want a predicate but no arguments?

Comment: @Barry: fair point ;-) ... so check for a function type in predicate.